# Writerow does not print some variables to the csv file

Tags: python, csv

The following code is failing to write the name and address variables to a csv file.  When I test it using numbers or words, or the "write' variable, these will be recorded in the csv, but the "Writeaddress" and "WriteName" will not*.  (Also, using the original sources for these variables will also leave blanks)

```
import requests, sys, pyperclip, bs4, csv
StationList = open('CTA Station Addresses.csv', 'w', newline='')
StationWrite = csv.writer(StationList)
for i in range(149):
    id = str(i)
    res = requests.get('http://www.transitchicago.com/travel_information  /station.aspx?StopId=' + id)
    res.raise_for_status()
    Station = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    Name = Station.select('.rtehdng')
    Address = Station.select('#ctl07_divAddress')
    Write = 0
    if Name == []:
        print('missing name')
        Write = 1
    else:
        #print(Name[0].getText())
        WriteName = Name[0].getText()
        pass
    if Address == []:
        print('missing address')
        Write = 1
    else:
        #print(Address[0].getText())
        WriteAddress = Address[0].getText()
        pass
    if Write == 0:
        StationWrite.writerow([Write, WriteName, WriteAddress])
    Write = 0
StationList.close()
```

*(I can do "writerows([3, Write, Writename]) and the CSV row will be "3, 0, ")

Comment: I see you have a commented-out print statement and another that is not commented; what do those print?

Comment: Yes, *please* show the output from your debugging trace!

Comment: I ran your code with a few tweaks like removing spaces from the url and it did get values for `WriteName` and `WriteAddress`. They contained newlines so the csv looked a little weird but they were there. I can't reproduce the problem. You ran this script?

Comment: @zondo Print Address.gettext and printname.get text were to show that this was downloading correctly (I haven't done web scraping before, so this is a learning project), these print the name and address for the station.for me to check that they had been downloaded.

Comment: @tdelaney:  The values definitely exist (see response to zondo, this part did not cause problems) the issue is that the csv ended up blank when I tried to write it.  I'll try out the next suggestion and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error but the data you get has embedded newlines and spaces which can make the csv look odd. I've cleaned up the script and scrubbed the data before writing the csv and ended up with station,address entries. I didn't see a need to write `Write` because it was always 0 in your script and doesn't even exist in mine since I leverage exception handling instead.

```
import requests, sys, pyperclip, bs4, csv

with open('CTA Station Addresses.csv', 'w', newline='') as StationList:
    StationWrite = csv.writer(StationList)
    for i in range(149):
        _id = str(i)
        res = requests.get('http://www.transitchicago.com/travel_information/station.aspx?StopId=' + _id)
        res.raise_for_status()
        Station = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        try:
            name = Station.select('.rtehdng')[0].getText().strip()
            address = Station.select('#ctl07_divAddress')[0].getText().splitlines()[-1].strip()
        except IndexError as e:
            print("No data for station", _id)
            continue
        if not name or not address:
            print('Empty elements for station', _id)
            continue
        print(repr(name), repr(address))
        StationWrite.writerow([name, address])
```